# Firebase set roles to users

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a situation in Firebase where users have roles. According some profile already defined in another "schema" users can delete, update, create, delete and update, etc, etc... Many combinations are made.

Ex.:

```
Users/:
    user_1:
        create: "ok"
        delete: "no"
        update: "ok"
    user_2:
        create: "no"
        ... etc ...
```

How manage this in firebase once ".write' permission do not accept dynamic condition? I found Bolt that have some alias (*create()*, *update()*, *delete()*) to that however, you have only create **OR** update **OR** delete. Once one is defined you cannot change.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe try making a linux chmod-style field per-user and creating the permissions that way? That way you only have one field and define all combinations once in your permissions.

Comment: Just to be precise, Bolt is an experimental security and rules COMPILER and is in Beta.

Comment: Hi @PrestonGarno. Yes, this works. Recover the role is possible but fits a condition that represent the role is the part I have no ideia how to do. You can recover the role saying 777 or 765 etc but you cannot change the rule for .write in firebase according this.

Comment: I haven't ever used Bolt, but from what I remember in standard Firebase rules is that you can set permissions based on field values on nodes, no? There's also custom user tokens that I remember implementing.  I do remember it being challenging though! Have you checked the updated (Google) API docs yet? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security

Comment: I meant that in the .write/.read rules in the firebase rules file, you would write out all of the different combinations for the chmod rules.  Then just have a field called 'access' or something that is for each user a number representing their access level on that particular "branch" of the DB.  Then simply change the number for each user when you want to change their access rights.

Comment: Yes! I already have. But in function of this "number/role" I need to change the rule to write... and is exactly this I can't do it.

Comment: It's a kind of have conditional rule for each role... if you are "777 or writer" you have complete access (update/delete/edit), if you have "765 or deleter" you can just delete... and for the action you haver rights the firebase ".write" should adapt to fits your profile. That is the point I don't know how to deal with. :)

Comment: I'm typing up an answer now, I hope I understand your question and am able to solve it:)

Comment: I guess I have also a solution... I am trying right now! Back soon here! :)

Comment: @PrestonGarno take a look and let me know if you do not agree! :)

Comment: Firebase just launched support for role based access via custom user claims on the ID token: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution... no ideia if is the best one... however, solve my problem.
In any case, is a little painful to write the conditions.

[image: users roles"]

and then in your firebase rules:

[image: firebase rules]

**CUD** means **C**reate **U**pdate **D**elete. You can use chmod numbers as well (777, 765, etc).

Now, I need to discover how to write the conditions for -ud, --d, etc. 
:)

Comment: That could work, but also could get messy.  Have a look at my solution and let me know what you think.  I preferred to take the route of a per-'main' node permission structure because it seemed more flexible.  Remember - don't be afraid to have a bunch of entries - seems counterintuitive but the DB is set up to be scattered all over the place yet allow easy maintenance/organization

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so I'm going to assume that your data is structured something like below. This answer is my own subjective approach to how I would dynamically manage users accessing different parts of the DB.

**NOTE**::the chmod that I use stands for READ-WRITE-DELETE, instead of READ-WRITE-EXECUTE (i.e. 6=read+write but not delete, 7=full CRUD privileges).  This sample DB is structured in 3 parts, and models a social media app.  Also, the default for the "world" (3rd digit would most likely be only authenticated users. This is a very simple example:

```
root/
 |
 |-- user/                 <-main node that contains profile info
 |       \uid              <-node name - one for each user with sub-nodes containing profile info
 |       \user            
 |          |-<UID>        <-shows who has "user" privileges (1st digit)
 |        \group
 |          |-<UID>        <-shows who has "group" privileges (1st digit)
 |    \permissions = 744   <-universal "user" entry rule
 |
 |-- trending/             <-node that contains global, read only info
 |       \user             <-No one will be here for "trending"
 |       \group
 |       \feed-data
 |           \<POST_UUIDS> <-Data here
 |       \permissions = 444 <-Everyone can read the global feed
 |
 |-- messaging/
 |      \<chat-uuid-number-1>            
 |           \user            
 |              |-<User1>
 |              |-<User2>
 |           \group 
 |           \messages node
 |      \<chat-uuid-number-2>            
 |           \user            
 |              |-<User8>
 |              |-<User5>
 |           \messages-node
 |
 |      \permissions = 600  <-Only 2 users can read&send messages in their node
 |
 |-- chatrooms/             <-each node contains a list of UID, and list of messages
 |     \<room-uuid-number>
 |        \user            
 |           |-<Admin1>
 |           |-<Admin2...>
 |        \group 
 |           |-<uid1>
 |           |-<uid2>
 |           |-<uid3...infinity>
 |      \permissions = 760    <-Only admins have user privilege, users in chat can send and receive in the chat though
```

So this is a somewhat `denormalized` database structure, like JSON databases are apparently supposed to be.  Read about this here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html  Each branch does not hold very much information except exactly what it is concerned with.  Now, if you have a unified "inheritance" type structure, then you can use relative directory paths to check relative to the directory that a user is trying to access and isolate the validation rules in one spot- at your root - and then all the children nodes will be covered as long as they all have uniform structure for basic permissions!

So as long as your new data is NEVER going into the root directory **or** any of the main nodes/directories below it (you can write rules to ensure this also), you use data.parent() to get to the parent of your entry, then call parent() again to get to the main directory (e.g. chatroom), then you check the permissions value for each consecutive number, and match against the list of users/group/world:

```
".write": "data.parent().parent().child('permissions').val().beginsWith('6') && data.parent().child('users').child($uid).exists"
```

This (pseudocode?) checks the first digit of the permissions code, and then checks the node's "users" subdir to see if the current user has user privileges for that particular sub-node. Add a conditional OR after this to check and see if there's `group` writing privileges and the user exists in the group. And so on... all from the root directory! Just make sure you guard against writing under '/' or '//' (write those conditionals first using '&&' so it fails the check before trying to get parent of the root, etc.) and it should work well.

This isn't an absolute structure, but I set mine up to be 'shallow' database all while restricting each entry under a major directory like "messages" to have a permissions code and check for that UID of the user making the DB read/write, and it saved me a ton of pain down the line.  Although the last time I used it was about 5 months ago, I'm not sure if things have gotten simpler or simple tools/libraries exist now. Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!!! I'll take a look carefully. In any case, I just pushed a solution that (until now) is working for me.

Comment: @Mario no problem, hope you figure it out either way.  And if this does work for you, don't forget to mark it correct:)  Good luck.

Comment: @Mario One thing I forgot to make clear: `permissions` node is at "/messages/permissions" (directly under main node) *defining the rules for every single message conversation*. And then the `user` and `group` nodes exist on a *per chat* basis, so it'd be /messages/<chat-entry-number>/users and /messages/<chat-entry-number>/group, so 1 per message chat. I think my root rules is incorrect that's why I'm clarifying

Comment: Ok! Thanks again!

Comment: https://fadeit.dk/blog/2016/08/25/firebase-advanced-data-modelling-and-role-based-authentication-authorization/