# Can any one please tell me how to put Logic for multi role user login Firebase in android studio

Tags: firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

//I am adding different users like student,driver and parent to Firebase FireStore
//Authentication work fine but I want that user(Student go to STUDENT_ACTIVITY after login) and vice versa.

//CODE

```
private void loginUser(){
    String email = etLoginEmail.getText().toString();
    String password = etLoginPassword.getText().toString();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        etLoginEmail.setError("Email cannot be empty");
        etLoginEmail.requestFocus();
    }else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        etLoginPassword.setError("Password cannot be empty");
        etLoginPassword.requestFocus();
    }else{
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if (task.isSuccessful()){

                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "User logged in successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Log in Error: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how do you assign roles to each type of user? Then you do that in firebase/firestore. When you navigate to your database tab there is another tab titled "rules" where you can authorize roles to have different permissions for "read/write"

As seen here:

[Firebase set roles to users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43866550/firebase-set-roles-to-users)

If you are asking how to redirect a user to a page associated with their roles after login? Then this is done in routing when programming your front end. Usually with a method that routes the user to a page, or load a document after selecting the login button.

As seen here in this answer

[Firebase, how to redirect after login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48787554/firebase-how-to-redirect-after-login)